# sources list in home folder

Tags: apt, software-sources

I don't have SU permissions in my school computer so i want to create a local `sources.list` in my home folder so I can add my own source to `apt`.

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Ho do you want to use these sources without root privileges?

Comment: Basically I want to download only the source code using apt (doesn't require sudo). But for some reason the sources.list is empty

Comment: Using the source code I would compile locally the app and make my own app folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. If you could it would be a security problem since the software installed is added to the base system and you need admin permissions for that.

The only way to install software in your home is by installing the source version (mainly supplied with a `.tar.gz` file).  But even if you could install software like that I would ask for permission. It is NOT your computer.

If you can use the USB you could create a live USB at home and use that. Also: I would ask permission for that method too.